# NW.js Can't Switch Between Sdk and Normal Flavors Error: rcedit.exe failed with exit code 1

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, node-webkit

I face some strange behavior, at least it's strange for me. When I build the NW.js project with `"nwFlavor": "normal"` within my *package.json* it's all good, all works as expected. Once I'm changing to `"nwFlavor": "sdk"` I'm geting the error listed below.

**How I dealt with it earlier:**

I had that exact same error in my previous project earlier and I managed to solve this issue by deleting all **node_modules** then switching to the newest **nw.js** version and `npm install` all again. By far I don't think that this is the right way to solve this issue but it worked for me.

**Predictions:**

I'm not sure but maybe that happens because a newer nw.js version has been released. Now I am using 0.51.1 and the stock version is 0.51.2 at the moment of writing. Maybe it tries to download sdk version of 0.51.2 at the time my project is using 0.51.1. Not sure.

**Question**

What happens with the flavor so that I can't switch between sdk and normal binaries over time? If the issue listed above related to the cached flavor so how to reset that cache without deleting node_modules so that the flavor binaries can be downloaded again?

Thankful in advance for your time.

**Error after editing a package.json and switch from `"nwFlavor": "normal"` to `"nwFlavor": "sdk"`**

```js
*** Vue stuff

 DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
 INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

Starting building tasks... { tasks: [ [ 'win', 'x64' ] ], concurrent: false }
Building for win, x64 starts...
Fetching NW.js binary... { platform: 'win', arch: 'x64', version: '0.51.1', flavor: 'sdk' }
Building targets...
Building directory target starts...
Error: rcedit.exe failed with exit code 1. Fatal error: Unable to commit changes
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\PROJECT\MY_PROJECT\node_modules\rcedit\lib\rcedit.js:60:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
Building for win, x64 ends within 1.39s.
```

Answer (score 2):

NW.js does not have any official build tool. I assume you are using [nw-vue-cli-example](https://github.com/nwutils/nw-vue-cli-example) which uses nwjs-builder-phoenix.

If you are having issues with that build tool, you can:

1. Create an issue with their repo.

   - Nevermind, that repo is now marked as Archived, so no issues can be made.
2. Look into [forks](https://github.com/evshiron/nwjs-builder-phoenix/network) of the repo to see if there are any alternatives that have improved on it or who could help you.
3. Write your own build script unique to your project (this is pretty common in the NW.js community)
4. Look into alternative build tools

   - https://github.com/nwjs-community/nw-builder
5. Help contribute to the build tool I'm working on

   - https://github.com/nwutils/nw-utils-builder

Comment: Thank you for your structured suggestions. What I mostly like about NW.js is that it has js to bin conversion. On other hand, Electron has a larger community but I read that they are not planning to evolve that path because of the performance problems. Are you planning to add the js to bin feature to your build tool?

Comment: It would not be difficult to include that feature. The harder part downloading and caching thing correctly. and writing tests for everything.

Comment: You are right about phoenix-builder I guess maybe phoenix-builder even if it now somehow works, later then it would be impossible to use it since the repo is no longer supported. I think it would be too much but at the same time really interesting if NW.js would have a simple GUI that will bring its possibilities to the vast number of users that are not familiar with the command-line tools. The thing that could make a simple UI like bootstrap.  IMHO it would stand out from Electron.